# DLL load failed, module not found?

Tags: python, dll

I have a folder with a file "main.py" and a file "_test.pyd" (note **.pyd**). The file "main.py" looks like this:

```
import _test
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import _test
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _test: The specified module could not be found.
```

Why is this error coming up? Cheers.

Note: I was given this code by others, and it works for the original authors, so I'm not sure what's wrong with me/my machine.

**Update:** Running `os.path.isfile('_test.pyd')` returns `True`, so I don't think it's a problem with the path

Comment: you might need to add the path containing the module to your sys.path. import sys then try sys.path.append('PATH_WITH_PYD') *before* importing _test.

Comment: @nomansland008 thanks for your comment, unfortunately the path was already in sys.path. Just to be safe I added another .py file in the folder and tried importing it and it worked correctly, so the issue might have something to do with the module being a .pyd file maybe?

Comment: looking into the semantics/differences of how a .pyd works sounds like the right direction. I don't know much else about how to help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You should append the path of the folder which contains the imported module before import.

**Code:**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

import _test  # noqa: E402
```

**EDIT:**

Other ideas:

- Adding `__init__.py` file to the related director.
- Checking the `PyInit_foo()` function in `.pyd` file.

  - If the Python finds the `.pyd` file, it will attempt to call `PyInit_foo()` to initialize it

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but your proposed solution does not work unfortunately. The directory of the .pyd file was in fact already in sys.path. I'm starting to think it might not be a directory issue.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` file is the directory? Does your PYD contain `PyInit_foo() ` function? Because if the `Python` finds your PYD file, it will attempt to call `PyInit_foo()` to initialize it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment -- as per my own answer above, somehow downgrading Python solved the issue. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You are welcome. The point is that you succeeded. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Following posts from people experiencing similar issues, I tried downgrading my Python version (from 3.8.4rc1 to 3.5.4) and the import now works correctly. No clue why. I guess the .pyd file was written in that version of Python (I'm not the author of the file), but still I'm clueless as to what the exact origin of the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this error and what I found after a lot of investigation:-

issue was in Opencv==4.5.1 build from source with cuda and flag `cuda_with_fast_math=on`

I just rebuild OpenCV and disable

```
cuda_with_fast_math
```

and it works for me.